# Calculate Tweets Per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I need to write a function which calculates the number of tweets that were posted per day.

Function Specifications:

- It should take a pandas dataframe as input.
  It should return a new dataframe, grouped by day, with the number of tweets for that day.
- The index of the new dataframe should be named Date, and the column of the new dataframe should be 'Tweets', corresponding to the date and number of tweets, respectively.
- The date should be formated as yyyy-mm-dd, and should be a datetime object.

My code is :

```
def number_of_tweets_per_day(df):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(twitter_df['Date','Tweets'], columns =['Date', 'Tweets'])
    
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m%d')
    df['Tweets'] = df['Tweets'].astype(str)
    
    grouped = pd.df.groupby(['Date'],['Tweets'])
    final = pd.df.count()
    
    
    
    return final
```

However when I try to run command 'number_of_tweets_per_day(twitter_df.copy())' I get an error saying twitter_df not defined.

**DF**:
[image: DataFrame]

**Expected output**:
[image: Expected Output]

Attached links to an image of input dataframe and image of expected output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should `twitter_df` be the argument in `def`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pd.Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) to group and use [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) here.

```
def tweets_per_day(df):
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    return df[['Tweets']].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).count()
  # return df['Tweets'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).count() 
  # if you want output to be `Series`

tweets_per_day(twitter_df)
```

Output on dummy df:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(['2019-11-29', '2019-11-30']).repeat(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tweets':'anything', 'Date':d})
df
#      Tweets       Date
#0   anything 2019-11-29
#1   anything 2019-11-30
#2   anything 2019-11-29
#3   anything 2019-11-30
#4   anything 2019-11-29
#5   anything 2019-11-30
#6   anything 2019-11-29
#7   anything 2019-11-30
#8   anything 2019-11-29
#9   anything 2019-11-30
#10  anything 2019-11-29
#11  anything 2019-11-30
#12  anything 2019-11-29
#13  anything 2019-11-30
#14  anything 2019-11-29
#15  anything 2019-11-30
#16  anything 2019-11-29
#17  anything 2019-11-30
#18  anything 2019-11-29
#19  anything 2019-11-30

tweets_per_day(df)

            Tweets
Date
2019-11-29      10
2019-11-30      10
```

Answer (score 0):

The `groupby()` technique demonstrated by @Ch3steR certainly works.  Here are two other approaches, using `value_counts()` and `resample()`:

Create the data frame (and set data type):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':  ['2019-11-30'] * 5 + ['2019-11-29'] * 6,
                   'Tweets': 'x'}
                 )
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

The `value_counts()` approach:

```
def tweets_per_day_2(df):
    return df['Date'].value_counts().sort_index()

result = tweets_per_day_2(df)
print(result)

2019-11-29    6
2019-11-30    5
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

And the `resample()` approach:

```
def tweets_per_day_3(df):
    return df.set_index('Date').resample('D').count().sort_index()

result = tweets_per_day_3(df)
print(result)

            Tweets
Date              
2019-11-29       6
2019-11-30       5
```